# How can i load a BufferedImage to my runnable JAR file?

Tags: java, jar, path, load, bufferedimage

I'm trying to export a JAR file from my project and I need some of my `BufferedImage`s to get loaded in it.

Structure is this:

```
-src
  -img
  -models
  -views
```

...
and knowing that all my image files are stored into the `img` package. I'm trying to do this in a `JPanel` from other project:

```
public class BelowPanel extends JPanel {

    private BufferedImage img;

    public BelowPanel() {
        initImage();
        setOpaque(false);
    }

    private void initImage() {
        try {
             img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream(("/img/titan.png")));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2.drawImage(img, 0, 0,this.getWidth(),this.getHeight(), this);
    }
}
```

When I run this it shows the image, but once I  generate the JAR file in my desktop, it doesn't even run.

My images of `Image` type, doesn't have any problem, but `BufferedImage`s doesn't load.

So... Do you know a way to load my "titanImage", so I can generate a running JAR file which can work correctly?

Comment: How do you know the problem is related to loading images if your application *"doesn't even run"*..?

Comment: @haraldK i've created another project, with only two panels, above panel and below panel which is the class you can see in my question. above panel paint an Image of type Image, and belowClass paint another Image but from the type BufferedImage.

if i dont call initImage() in the belowPanel and generate the jar, it runs with the Image of the abovePanel, but if i call it, jar doesnt open. Thats all with my project does, paint two panels with two images.